# Adicionar varios itens em uma lista

Tags: c#, .net, collection

Existe alguma forma de adicionar vários `Int`em uma `list<int>`de uma unica vez?

Tipo

```
List<Int32> ContasNegativas = new List<Int32>();

ContasNegativas.AddRange(30301, 30302, 30303, 30304, 30305, 30306, 30341, 30342, 30343, 30344, 30345, 30346, 30401,30403, 30421, 30423, 40101, 40102, 40111, 40112, 40121, 40122, 40123, 50101, 50102, 50103, 50104, 50105, 50231);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu raciocínio está quase certo, a única diferença é que o método [`AddRange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) recebe um `IEnumerable<T>` ao invés de vários `T`'s.

O uso ficaria:

```
ContasNegativas.AddRange(new [] {30301, 30302, 30303, 30304});
```

Obs.: O C# é suficientemente inteligente para enteder que `new [] {int, ...}` se refere a um novo array de inteiros.

Você também pode passar um `List` como parâmetro (porque a classe `List` também implementa `IEnumerable`).

```
var novaLista = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
ContasNegativas.AddRange(novaLista);
```

ou

```
ContasNegativas.AddRange(new List<int> {1, 2, 3});
```

Comment: Cara perfeito vlw...

Answer (score 4):

Você pode adicioná-los como um enumerable (por exemplo, um array):

```
List<Int32> ContasNegativas = new List<Int32>();
ContasNegativas.AddRange(new int[] { 30301, 30302, 30303, 30304, 30305, 30306, 30341, 30342, 30343, 30344, 30345, 30346, 30401,30403, 30421, 30423, 40101, 40102, 40111, 40112, 40121, 40122, 40123, 50101, 50102, 50103, 50104, 50105, 50231 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Seria colocando no inicializador.

```
var lista = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Isso que precisa?